# Why does the ESP referring to the address in a stack jumps 4h each time?

Tags: pointers, assembly, stack, stack-pointer

Why doesn't the Extended Stack Pointer (ESP) jump 1h in each PUSH or POP operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `PUSH` pushes one whole register to the stack. On 32bit machines, that's four byte's worth of data.

`PUSHQ` would change RSP by 8 in x86_64 because it pushes 64 bits.

Comment: Your answer is brief, clear,easy, fast, and accurate. thanks for clearing things up for me.